# Custom pip.conf location for pip 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I manage a group of Ubuntu 16.04 servers with Python 3.5 and pip 8.1.1 as part of the OS package. The servers do not have access to the Internet and `pip` needs to be configured with internal pypi mirror.

I have the following config file at `/home/hanxue/.config/pip/pip.conf`

```
[global]
index-url = https://pypimirror/simple
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Unfortunately pip 8.1.1 does not read the config file located at `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`. Only pip version >10 and above use the more consistent XDG path at `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`

I have tried setting the `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable but pip 8.1.1 is not picking it up

```
$ PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/home/hanxue/.config/pip/pip.conf /usr/bin/pip3 search tensorflow
```

I know I can just create a copy of the file at `~/.pip/pip.conf` to solve the problem. But this is for the end users, and they will end up with 2 `pip.conf`  and thus generating confusion down the road. For example, editing `~/.pip/pip.conf` but found out that pip 19 / python 3.6 does not pick up the settings.

How can I get pip 8.1 to pick up the config from a non-standard location?

Comment: Why not just have one `~/.pip/pip.conf` for all?

Comment: @phd pip >= 9.0 does not read `~/.pip/pip.conf`. Config files should be under `~/.config` anyway, rather than have their separate dot directories in `$HOME`

Comment: My `pip 19.0.3` perfectly reads it. Configs must be there where programs expect them. If old versions of `pip` read `~/.pip/pip.conf` and new versions read both `~/.pip/pip.conf` and `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` the portable solution is to put config into `~/.pip/pip.conf`.

Comment: For whatever reason, I use `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` again with pip 8.1.1 (Ubuntu 16.04) and pip 8.1.2 (CentOS 7.4) and pip is picking up the non-standard `pip.conf` location. I am not keen to use `~/.pip/pip.conf` because it's not XDG compliant, and is noted as legacy path https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/19.2.1/src/pip/_internal/configuration.py#L81-L86

Comment: For me it's exactly the other way around: I don't care about XDG, I certainly prefer `~` orver `~/.config`, and I don't want to define an additional env var.

Answer (score 3):

### pip 9.0 and newer

If you are using the latest version of pip now, or any version above 9.0.0, the configuration file should be in `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`. Per the [official pip user guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/):

> On Unix the default configuration file is: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf` which respects the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable.
>
> On macOS the configuration file is `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf` if directory `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip` exists else `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`.
>
> On Windows the configuration file is `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`.

The documentation explicitly states that `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf` is a legacy path, and the [configuration file function in pip's source is similarly named legacy](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/19.2.1/src/pip/_internal/configuration.py#L81-L86).

### pip 8.x.x and older

Tell pip that your configuration file is located at `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf` with the `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable

```
$ PIP_CONFIG_FILE=~/.config/pip/pip.conf /usr/bin/pip3 install --user colorama
Collecting colorama
```

This has been tested working with pip 8.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 and pip 8.1.2 on CentOS 7.4

Comment: Note the `pip` user guide could be clearer. If `pip` respects `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, then the default is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pip/pip.conf`, which happens to be `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` if `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is empty or unset.

Comment: @chepner yeah, it's not picking up `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. IMO it is a bug - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6849

Comment: I commented on a possible error in your bug report; looking at [the source code](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/800f866600968997dd6d9e49076b401784195123/src/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py#L147), `pip` should be doing the right thing.